# SSH server allows login but refuses connection when trying to copy a file

Tags: ssh, rsync, scp

I am able to log into my ssh server both using a password and also with key. But when I try to copy a local file to the ssh server (rsync or scp) it refuses the connection which is very strange.

So this works, and I am able to log in:

```
$ ssh martins@192.168.1.10 -p 43316

Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-135-generic x86_64)
```

But when I try to copy a file it gives me an error:

```
$ scp -P 36191 ~/Documents/test.txt martins@192.168.1.10:~/Documents/

ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.10 port 36191: Connection refused
lost connection
```

```
$ rsync -azP -e "ssh -p 36191" ~/Documents/rsync-test/ martins@192.168.1.10:~/Documents/rsync-test-server

ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.10 port 36191: Connection refused
lost connection
```

I can't understand what is going on here. How can login work fine but file copy not?

Comment: I think your problem is because your `ssh` is connected by using the port `43316` and both scp and rsync are using the port `36191`

Comment: Oh, I am an idiot. Thanks @EdgarMagallon

Comment: No worries! These things happen :)